# No cabal file found - Haskell in Atom

Tags: haskell, ghc, atom-editor, cabal

I installed Haskell ghc-mod and all the other haskell packages in atom and had some problems with the paths and so on.

Now this seems all to work okay,  but I get the message: "no cabal file found" as an error in the toggle panel.

[image: Screenshot showing error message]

Does anyone know how to solve that? I don't get what cabal is at all and why my haskell in atom is still not working fine.

Comment: Try setting up a stack project. For ghc-mod to work you need either a cabal project or a stack project (and then place your source code inside the project). ghc-mod requires the project metadata to find and then check your code. It's kind of a hassle. For my money I think it's easier to get started with stack. Documentation here: http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#quick-start-guide / And if you're just writing a single Haskell file I find that hlint and ghci are Good Enough.™

Comment: Try doing `cabal init` on your root source directory and then try again.

Comment: i will try both. Thanks for response